# How do I make my website remember variables?

Tags: asp.net

I want to make my website remember variables for each user and display them, something like local storage that I can use in c#. What is the best way to achieve this concept?

Comment: Database and/or SessionState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Session State is what you are looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx

Or if you want permanent storage (ie they leave and come back another day)

Connecting to a SQL Server database.